# Save image on server

Tags: image, jakarta-ee, save, jersey

I have a BufferedImage in my jersey post call and would like to save it on the server.  I can save it to the file system but I want to save it to the server img folder.

EG localhost:8080/server/img

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the getRealPath() method of the ServletContext [ServletContext.getRealPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) to find out the actual directory in your filesystem and save it there. In your case it can be like

```
String realPathOfImgFolder=req.getServletContext().getRealPath("/img");
```

Then save the file to this location and it will be available by `http://localhost:8080/server/img/<image file name with extension>`